# In a Drupal Views argument, how can I get the total number of nodes in a nodequeue?

Tags: drupal, view, arguments

I'm working on a site that is a database of thousands record albums and am attempting to create an "album of the day" block. My solution has been to create a nodequeue of specific records, create a view that passes the current day of the year as an argument, and then uses this value to call the nodequeue item with that same numbered position. I do this by providing a "Default Argument" as PHP code in the "Nodequeue: Position" argument setting. Here's the code I use:

```
$nodequeueTotalNodes = 120;
$dayOfTheYear = date("z");
$nodeQueuePosition = $dayOfTheYear % $nodequeueTotalNodes;
return $nodeQueuePosition;
```

The above code works to my satisfaction but my problem is I have to manually change the value of $nodequeueTotalNodes every time I add or remove an item from my nodequeue.

Is there a way to pull the total number of nodes from my queue to replace the "120" in my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodequeue_nodes table holds all the nodes in your queues. Something like this should do the trick, where qid is the queue id:

```
$nodequeueTotalNodes = db_result(db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {nodequeue_nodes} WHERE qid = %d', $qid));
```

If you're using a subqueue there's a column called sqid which you can use.